# Seek phpredis redisArray consistent hashing algorithm info

Tags: php, twemproxy

We are using phpredis redisArray to distribute keys on 2 servers. But we now we have a new need to use same data set with other languages than php.

So can anybody suggest which hash function (crc32. crc32a, jenkins...etc) in combination with which key distribution mode (ketama, modula etc) should be used to get correct result to build library to match redisArray distribution.

Note that we can't rehash as dataset is very huge like 200M+ .

We are also thinking of using twemproxy (https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) but hashing & key distribution is not matching with phpredis redisArray distribution.

Can anybody guide us on this?